# vim: How do I map number keys?

Tags: vim

Not sure why this isn't working, but I can't map Ctrl+NUMBER to a command in vim.

For example this works:

```
nnoremap <C-r> :bufdo bdelete<cr>
```

This doesn't:

```
nnoremap <C-8> :bufdo bdelete<cr>
```

Do I have to do something special in order to map number keys?

`gvim 7.4, Windows 7`

Comment: Not all keys are map-able. Much of this is due to how vim receives the key codes from the terminal. Looking for which keys to map try here: `:h map-which-keys`. I feel that a mapping to `:bufdo bdelete` feels a bit wrong.

Comment: [It is possible in Xterm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631241).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This [does not appear to be possible](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/iszb6GfvkRU) for reasons of portability.

Answer (score 20):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>non-alphabetic</kbd> cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated [various proposals](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8).

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.